# Matrix addition over multiple files using e.g. awk

Tags: matrix, awk

I have a bunch of files from simulation output, all with the same number of rows and fields.
What I need to do is to combine them, so that I get only one file with the numbers summed up, which basically resembles the addition of several matrices.

Example:

File1.txt

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

File2.txt

```
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
```

File3.txt

```
3 3 3
3 3 3 
3 3 3
```

required output

```
6 6 6
6 6 6
6 6 6
```

I'm going to integrate this into some larger Shell-script, therefore I would prefer a solution in awk, though other languages are welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[FNR,i]=$i+a[FNR,i]}
END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)
      for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)printf "%s%s", a[i,j],(j==NF?"\n":FS)}' f1 f2 f3
```

input files could be more than 3

test with your data:

```
kent$  head f[1-3]
==> f1 <==
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1

==> f2 <==
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2

==> f3 <==
3 3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3

kent$  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[FNR,i]=$i+a[FNR,i]}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)printf "%s%s", a[i,j],(j==NF?"\n":FS)}' f1 f2 f3
6 6 6
6 6 6
6 6 6
```

Comment: Hell, this was quick! Working perfectly, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack:

```
paste f1 f2 f3 | awk '{for(i=1;i<=m;i++)printf "%d%s",$i+$(i+m)+$(i+2*m),i==m?ORS:OFS}' m=3
```